# How much time certain string mentioned in dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

I have dictionary where key is color_name and value is list of color_name similar to mentioned as key color

```py
all_colors = {
    'red': ['coral','burgundy'],
    'yellow':['mustard','lemon']}
```

I have pandas dataframe

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'market_color': ['red',
                      'coral',
                      'burgundy',
                      'light red',
                      'mustard',
                      'lemon',
                      'red'],
     'color_id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]})
```

I want to count how much time color_name from all_colors and it's similarities mentioned in dataframe market_color column.

Expecting final dictionary like this `all_colors_frequencies={'red':5,'yellow':2}`

How i can achive it

Comment: You don't have light red in the list of similar colors,  why it was added to the tally of red?

Comment: Because light red contain red

Comment: What happens if you have `'light coral'`, does it counts as red also?

Comment: `light coral` also should be counted as red

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function that iterates through the map and tries to match the value to one of the keys

```
def categorize(col, map):
    result = "Unknown"
    for key, color_list in map.items():
        if col == key or col in color_list:
            return key
    return result
```

Then you apply that function to the col `market_color` and use value_counts to get the final count for each key

```
df.market_color.apply(lambda col: categorize(col, all_colors)).value_counts()
```

The following snippet:

```
all_colors={'red':['coral','burgundy','light red'], 'yellow':['mustard','lemon']}
df={
    'market_color':['red','coral','burgundy','light red','mustard','lemon','red'],
    'color_id':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)

def categorize(col, map):
    result = "Unknown"
    for key, color_list in map.items():
        if col == key or col in color_list:
            return key
    return result
    
print(df.market_color.apply(lambda col: categorize(col, all_colors)).value_counts())
```

Would give the following output:

```
red       5
yellow    2
Name: market_color, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach using [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) and [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
reverse_lookup = {v: k for k, vs in all_colors.items() for v in vs}


def repl(m):
    return reverse_lookup[m.group()]


# map similar colors to key colors
normal = df["market_color"].str.replace("|".join(reverse_lookup), repl=repl, regex=True)

# extract only colors, i.e. light red -> red
colors_only = normal.str.extract(f'({"|".join(all_colors)})', expand=False)

# count and transform to dict
res = colors_only.value_counts().to_dict()
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
{'red': 5, 'yellow': 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to map from an explicit list, this should be sufficient;

```
all_colors = {'red': ['coral', 'burgundy', 'light red'],
              'yellow':['mustard', 'lemon']}

d = {k: v for v,l in all_colors.items() for k in l}
# {'coral': 'red', 'burgundy': 'red', 'mustard': 'yellow', 'lemon': 'yellow'}

out = df['market_color'].map(lambda x: d.get(x, x)).value_counts().to_dict()
```

Output: `{'red': 5, 'yellow': 2}`

Answer (score 0):

Here a possible solution without using `apply`, `for` loops or `if`.

## Data

here I slightly change your data adding a light coral which is going to be code as red and a light pink which is not listed in `all_color`

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'market_color': ['red',
                      'coral',
                      'burgundy',
                      'light red',
                      'light pink',
                      'light coral',
                      'mustard',
                      'lemon',
                      'red']})
df["color_id"] = df.index + 1
# we keep a copy of the original data
df_bk = df.copy()

all_colors = {'red': ['coral','burgundy'], 
     'yellow':['mustard','lemon']}
```

## `all_colors` dictionary

Here we want a dictionary which associate the parent color

```py
diz = {}
for k, v in all_colors.items():
    diz[k] = k
    for i in v:
        diz[i] = k
```

which looks like

```bash
{'red': 'red',
 'coral': 'red',
 'burgundy': 'red',
 'yellow': 'yellow',
 'mustard': 'yellow',
 'lemon': 'yellow'}
```

## Step-by-step

First we split each color with multiple words

```py
df["mc_split"] = df["market_color"].str.split()
```

which return

```bash
  market_color  color_id        mc_split
0          red         1           [red]
1        coral         2         [coral]
2     burgundy         3      [burgundy]
3    light red         4    [light, red]
4   light pink         5   [light, pink]
5  light coral         6  [light, coral]
6      mustard         7       [mustard]
7        lemon         8         [lemon]
8          red         9           [red]
```

Then we explode these lists

```py
df = df.explode("mc_split")
```

so we have

```bash
  market_color  color_id  mc_split
0          red         1       red
1        coral         2     coral
2     burgundy         3  burgundy
3    light red         4     light
3    light red         4       red
4   light pink         5     light
4   light pink         5      pink
5  light coral         6     light
5  light coral         6     coral
6      mustard         7   mustard
7        lemon         8     lemon
8          red         9       red
```

And finaly we can use the dictionary `diz` above and count the values

```py
df["mc_split"].map(diz).value_counts().to_dict()
```

which returns

```bash
{'red': 6, 'yellow': 2}
```

keep in mind that we added a *light coral* that's why we have an extra red.

## One step only

From the original dataframe we could just use

```py
df = df_bk.copy()

df["market_color"].str.split()\
    .explode()\
    .map(diz)\
    .value_counts()\
    .to_dict()
```

which returns the expected output

```bash
{'red': 6, 'yellow': 2}
```